# IOS 7 safari ignoring viewport tag

Tags: html, css, ios7, responsive-design

If you look at [this site](http://www.showsec.co.uk) in Safari on an IOS7 device you will see that the content is zoomed in slightly and the page can be scrolled horizontally. It doesn't do this on other mobile devices, on my nexus for example it fits the screen perfectly as it should and you can only scroll vertically. It used to be fine on IOS6 but since the change to IOS7 its started behaving wierdly.

I've got the following viewport tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: Tested: iPad Air IOS 7.0.4 - Works fine. Can only scroll vertically.

Comment: `body { overflow:hidden }` may be

Comment: [**Image 1**](http://s21.postimg.org/jfqodgcue/photo_1.jpg) & [**Image 2**](http://s21.postimg.org/w8esddog6/photo_2.jpg) - Here I took a couple screenshots for you (with scroll bars on screen) you can see only one scrollbar because that's the only way I could scroll. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The page width fixes at about 375px, iphone screens have a width of 320px (even the retina screens render this width).

Without you providing relevant code I cannot tell you a fix but that is what hits me as the issue.

Comment: Just looked in your code and seen this... `body, .container {min-width: 360px !important;}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Answer (score 0):

Cracked it finally! Andrew was right I needed to change the min width to 320px, I also had to remove width=device-width from the viewport tag

Comment: Glad I could help, if you have found your answer, please mark it as answered.

Comment: You should also keep the `width=device-width` in the viewport tag